# Ubuntu 22 wifi not working on kernel 6.2.036, gpu not working on kernel 6.2.0.35

Tags: 22.04, nvidia-geforce

I've ubuntu 22.04 recently installed but, in the default kernel 6.2.0-36 the wifi adapter is not detected. If I switch to the kernel 6.2.0-35 the problem is with the GUI, I get the black screen (nvidia-smi returns "nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver), if I switch to the terminal mode I can connect to wifi.

So with one kernel I don't have wifi and with the other I don't have GUI.

Is there a solution to this? I've tried reinstalling the nvidia drivers (3090 gpu) on the 6.2.0-35 version but there were no differences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer even though there might be some comments to be made.  I don't have a 3090 card, so I kind of have to guess.  There is a possibility that the 3090 can use the `-open` NVIDIA driver.  This is also assuming that you installed the `nvidia-driver-535` or a similar version from the repos.

When you boot into the `-36` kernel, what is the output of `dkms status`?  I have a feeling that the NVIDIA kernel is not installed into the `-35` kernel, and that can be corrected from the `-36` kernel using `dkms`.

The output of `dkms status` should look something similar to this:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ dkms status
nvidia/535.129.03, 6.2.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.129.03, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

As we can see that the NVIDIA driver is covered in 2 of the 3 installed kernel versions on my system.  So, I am going to now install the NVIDIA driver into the `5.15.0-88-generic` kernel version. *NOTE: This only works when the driver is installed using DKMS.*

```
sudo dkms install nvidia/535.129.03 -k 5.15.0-88-generic
```

Now checking after I ran the above command, I can see that the NVIDIA driver is now installed into the `5.15` kernel.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ dkms status
nvidia/535.129.03, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.129.03, 6.2.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.129.03, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Now when I reboot to the `5.15` kernel the video works fine.

Comment: dkms status is empty

Comment: @Rod0n Yep, use the driver from the repos and not from installing directly from NVIDIA.  The driver from NVIDIA is not DKMS ready and does not carry over into other Kernel versions.  You would have to manually install it into each Kernel.  DKMS is supposed to carry the driver into the next kernel automatically.

Comment: I've installed it from ubuntu-drivers.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the driver installed properly then.  It is supposed to install the `nvidia-driver-525` or `-535`.  Once those are installed the `dkms status` will show you a driver installed into the kernel.  Your issue is, the driver did not install properly so it is not carrying over or installed into the right kernel you need.  So, if you boot into the `-35` kernel you will need to install the driver again.  Maybe try installing from the terminal instead of using `ubuntu-drivers`.